# Show/hide script in jQuery shows only last hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

my simple script here

```
$(".showHide").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".showHide").children('.showHide').toggle();
});

$(".modal-inside").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
        if (e.which == 27) {
            $(".showHide").children('.showHide').hide();
        }
    });
```

It shows only last hided div, but I want it to show only direct child.

http://jsfiddle.net/yqaxqq6m/

Answer (score 1):

You need `$(this)` instead of `$(".showHide")` to get the children of event source element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqaxqq6m/1/)**

```
$(".showHide").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.showHide').toggle();
});
```

**Edit** to hide when click out side .modal-inside you can use `mouseup`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqaxqq6m/3/)**

```
$(".showHide").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.showHide').toggle();
});

$(".modal-inside").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('mouseup',  function(e) {  
    if (e.target.className != "modal-inside") {
        $(".showHide").children('.showHide').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the same, but then not works hidding div by click outside .modal-inside.

Comment: Thanks, but this hide my div even if I click even inside of  .modal-in. I need it to hide only if Is clicked outside.